# How can I use "Edit environment variable" editor for editing system variables instead of "Edit System Variable" editor

Tags: windows, environment-variables

Title said it all. I prefer to use "Edit environment variable" (fig 1), which can be seen when editing the `path` variable for your account, as you can see the entire view of paths. However, when editing the System variable `path`, "Edit system variable" screen shows up (fig 2). This semicolon separated edit control is harder to use than the former. Is there way to change the editor?

[image: Edit environment variable]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of windows are you using? On Windows 10 1909 version, when you go to Edit either the user environment or system environment variables, you are given the same window as your first screenshot. When you go to "Edit Text" is when you see the string value separated with semicolons.

The best thing I would suggest for editing the string value is using a CSV file that you can open in Excel or an equivalent program and easily edit the variables, then paste them back into Path.

Comment: I am using 18362. OK I need update.